# Birkhoff's definition of semilattice?

Tags: graph-theory, order-theory, lattice-orders

could anyone provide me with the original definition of semilattice by Garrett Birkhoff in his book on lattices? If you could also provide, page number and edition, it would be great (as well as some example, in case he gave some specific one).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the latest edition is fourth, I can only find the third, the definition is on page 6, see the picture for the statement.[image][image][image]

Comment: Well, youprovide the definition of lattice, BUT NOT that of semilattice......

Comment: Material added.

Comment: Thanks. Now it is better :)